# How to define a base route in Flask API routing system

Tags: python, api, routes, flask, restful-url

In some frameworks like slim php framework you can define base route that is the same in all routes like `/api/v1`.

So in slim we can group route to not put `/api/v1` in every route:

```
$app->group('/api/v1', function () use ($app) {

        // Get book with ID
        $app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Update book with ID
        $app->put('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

        // Delete book with ID
        $app->delete('/books/:id', function ($id) {

        });

});
```

But in Flask I couldn't find an easy way to group routes. What if I have to write `/api/v1` in every resource I call? Is there a way to group them?

In python I should use something like below:

```
class TaskListAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        pass

class TaskAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, id):
        pass

    def put(self, id):
        pass

    def delete(self, id):
        pass

api.add_resource(TaskListAPI, '/api/v1/tasks', endpoint = 'tasks')
api.add_resource(TaskAPI, '/api/v1/tasks/<int:id>', endpoint = 'task')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) are great, it looks like you are looking for a more specific extension, to suit your desire to build an API that easily differs between HTTP methods.

You might want to have a look at [Flask-Classy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/), which is a flask extension, that does just that. You can create a class per resource (just as you describe on your pseudocode) and differ on the http methods:

```python
from flask_classy import FlaskView


class TaskView(FlaskView):
    def index(self):
        """Return a list of all tasks."""
        pass

    def get(self, id):
        """Get a specific task."""
        pass

    def delete(self, id):
        """Delete the task."""
        pass

TaskView.register(app)
```

Additionally Flask-Classy supports a lot of ways to [customize the endpoints](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/#customizing-the-route-base), if you have special cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/). Blueprints are a great way to separate your app in to several smaller sections - for example, you might have a "main" blueprint for your web app, an "admin" blueprint for the admin interface and an "api" blueprint for your RESTful API.

Comment: As far as I know blueprints are used `for making application components and supporting common patterns within an application or across applications. Blueprints can greatly simplify how large applications work`